# mongodb multiple collection join with groupby

Tags: mongodb

I am noobie in mongodb,

but I am trying to aggregate data based on type of document(type_id)
I have following collections

items

```
{
    "_id" : "BE05332051E0AD282",
    "type_id" : "684EB00155D031225",//Organization or Book or Person
    "name" : "Owi Student Union",
    "structure" : {
        "organization_active_status" : "Inactive",
        "country" : "USA"
    },
    "hash" : "59E48A8C3F7B20",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -85.48172999999997,
            32.60746000000006
        ]
    },
    "geometry_confidence" : 0.0,
    "has_geometry" : true,
    "is_node" : false,
    "groupids" : [
        "DE05332041E0A4978"
]
}
```

tuples

```
{
    "_id" : "0E05333051E0A02E7",
    "source_id" : "BE05332051E0AD282",
    "destination_id" : "9E05332051E0AF344",
    "edge_id" : "DE05332051E0A3B5B",
    "direction" : NumberInt(1),
    "changed" : true
}
{
    "_id" : "0E05333061E0A02E8",
    "source_id" : "BE05332051E0AD282",
    "destination_id" : "0E05333051E0A02E7",
    "edge_id" : "DE05332051E0A3B5B",
    "direction" : NumberInt(1),
    "changed" : true
}
```

types

```
{
    "_id" : "684EB00155D031225",
    "name" : "Organization"
},
{
    "_id" : "BE0532A041E0AC077",
    "name" : "Book"
}
```

1. items collection contain all type of document for organization, books and can be differentiate on type_id
2. each organizations may have multiple books, person

relations

```
1) tuples.source_id = items._id
2) tuples.destination_id = items._id
3) items.type_id = type._id
```

I am trying aggregate data like this, but unable to get complete result

```
db.tuples.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "items",
            localField: "destination_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "source" 
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
           "source_id":"5BD5A377499D406EE05332051E0A93C2",
           "source.type_id" : "43B369EDE96A4876E0532A041E0A995A"
        }
    }
]);
```

Could any one help me on how can I create final result like this

Organizations

```
{
    "_id" : "BE05332051E0AD282",
    "type_id" : "684EB00155D031225",//Organization
    chapters : {
     "list of chapter(documents from item collection)"
    },
    books : { 
    "list of books(documents from item collection)"
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help or suggestion, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with aggregation pipeline as below. You can run it here,
https://mongoplayground.net/p/H2Ygqgjp2f5

```
    db.items.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "type_id": "684EB00155D031225"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "tuples",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "source_id",
      as: "tuples"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "items",
      let: {
        destination_ids: "$tuples.destination_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$destination_ids"
              ]
            },
            "type_id": "BE0532A041E0AC077"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "books"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "items",
      let: {
        destination_ids: "$tuples.destination_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$destination_ids"
              ]
            },
            "type_id": "BE0532A041E0AC087"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "persons"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "type_id": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "books": 1,
      "persons": 1
    }
  }
])
```

this would return a result as this.

```
  [
  {
    "_id": "BE05332051E0AD282",
    "books": [
      {
        "_id": "9E05332051E0AF344",
        "name": "Test Book 1",
        "type_id": "BE0532A041E0AC077"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Owi Student Union",
    "persons": [
      {
        "_id": "0E05333051E0A02E7",
        "name": "Test Person 1",
        "type_id": "BE0532A041E0AC087"
      }
    ],
    "type_id": "684EB00155D031225"
  }
]
```

But I would suggest you rethink your database design, since you are using a nosql database you should be able to embed documents and have a tree like structure. Hope this helps.

Comment: 1) there we get  array of tuples from 1st lookup so $tuples.detination_id will work? also it is taking longer time

Comment: Yes, here we get a list of all the books and persons and then join separately. We could always improve this for better performance. This is just an example way of getting the response you wanted.

Comment: update : yes the array is working fine, got the response for 1 org in 25 min, Could you suggest ay changes for performance improve

Comment: Okay. I am not sure how many data you have in your database. As a first step you can create indexes on all the fields that are used in filtering and joins. That should help you to improve the excution time.
Items - _id, type_id
tuples - source_id, destination_id
As a second step you can query persons & books together and get the result and filter in memory in your application.
Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.